# Angular wait until binding complete

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular5

In the purpose of scrolling to an element of a list after the view initialization completes, I'm trying to **getElementById** of an element that will be put into the DOM by an "***ngFor**" after making an **HTTP** call,

But the getElementById always returned **null** until I surround it with a **setTimeout** of 3sec, so it returns the element.

So I'm searching for a clean solution to wait until the binding into the view completes before I make getElementById.

## component.ts:

```
  InitDisponibilites(disponibilites) {
    this.disponibilites = Array();
    for (let disponibilite of disponibilites) {
      this.addDisponibilite(disponibilite);
    }

    setTimeout(()=>{

      let index = this.getElementIndexToScroll();
      let el = document.getElementById('dispo' + index) as HTMLElement;
      el.scrollIntoView();

    },3000);

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move that code either into `ionViewDidEnter` or `ionViewWillEnter` methods, those events are called based on ionic lifecycle. You can choose any of the two, depends on how soon you want the scroll effect.

Find more about ionic lifecycle events [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/navigation/NavController/#lifecycle-events)

If your use case lies in the subcomponent of a page, then you can't use ionic lifecycle event directly, instead use `@ViewChild` to access your component method to be called with page event.

```
@ViewChild(childComponent) childComponent: ChildComponent;
----------------------
----bunch of code ----
----------------------
ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.childComponent.willEnter(); //scroll logic will go inside the willEnter method.
}
```

**UPDATES**
If you are populating the child components as response to http, you can try using angular lifecycle event associated with the component `ngAfterViewInit()`, then check if given component index is the desired index, scroll it into the view.

**childcomponent.html**

```
<div #rootDiv [selected]="index === getElementIndexToScroll()"></div>
```

**childcomponent.ts**

```
export class ChildComponent implements AfterViewInit {
   @ViewChild('rootDiv') rootElement: ElementRef;
   @Input() selected: boolean;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (this.selected) {
       this.rootElement.nativeElement.scrollIntoView();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. I tried it using lifecycle, but all Ionic lifecycle are fired before the binding completes.
2. The problem with ViewChild that my element id is dynamically calculated, but the ViewChild accept a fixed element selector as I know.

Comment: Well `@ViewChild` does take input selector by attribute, so you can define custom index based attribute for your component, and then select using viewChild.
`<childComponent #selectedIdx></childComponent>`
`@ViewChild('selectedIdx') childComponent: ChildComponent;`